# I want to capture kafka matrice using prometheus and grafana using jmx port

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus

I want to capture kafka matrices using Prometheus and grafana using jmx port,But my Kafka is installed on cloudera flavour of hadoop and it is secured with kerberos.Please help me to configure prometheus with secured kafka.
   I tried to read to read data from jmx port,Getting below error:-

Get http://9.46.38.163:9393/metrics: dial tcp 9.76.38.123:9393: connect: connection refused

NOTE:-
Matrices is coming correctly if kerberos is not enabled.

Comment: do you mind adding a bit more context and specifics (topology, relevant configuration, etc)?

Comment: Do you mean you have single-sign-on (SPNEGO) ?